# Determining if $f(x) = \frac{x}{x+1}$ is Even or Odd

Tags: functions, even-and-odd-functions

This is likely a silly question, but I cannot seem to wrap my head around the following:

I am trying to determine whether the following function is even or odd: $f(x) = \frac{x}{x+1}$.

I pass $-x$ as input to the function to get: $f(-x) = \frac{-x}{-x+1}$.

The book I am using (Stewart Calculus 8th Edition) equates this to: $\frac{x}{x-1}$.

Thus, the equation is neither even or odd. However, what is the logic behind this last step?

Comment: Is it the case that $f(-x)=f(x)$ for all $x$? Is it the case that $f(-x)=-f(x)$ for all $x$? You can use the calculation you describe to answer these questions.

Comment: I understand that aspect. What I do not understand is how (-x)/(-x+1) is equal to x/(x-1)

Comment: Multiply both numerator and denominator by $-1$

Comment: Note that $-1(-x+1) = x-1$

Comment: Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for the mathematical formulas in your MSE questions. It is easy to learn and makes things much easier to read.

Comment: "Thus, the equation is neither even or odd." An *equation* cannot be even or odd. A *function* can be even or odd.

Answer (score 1):

By definition, if $f(-x)=f(x)$ then $f$ is even, and if $f(-x)=-f(x)$ then $f$ is odd.

From your calculation, you found: $f(-x) = \dfrac{-x}{-x+1}$. This can be rewritten as follows
\begin{align*}
f(-x) &= \frac{-x}{-x+1}\\
&= \frac{-(-x)}{-(-x+1)}\\
&= \frac{x}{x-1},
\end{align*}
where in the second equality I multiplied both the numerator and the denominator of the fraction by $-1$. So, $f(x)$ is neither even nor odd.